# How can I join lists that result from a for loop into one list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a for loop returning list of random letters. I want to get all these lists into one list.

```
import random

n = 3
for i in range (n ** 2):
    x = random.choice(["X", "Y"])
    x = list(x)

    print(x)
```

Ideally I would get x (or some other variable) to equal the outcomes of the for loop into one list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a list and then append each item to it with each iteration, like this:

```
import random

x = []

n = 3
for i in range (n ** 2):
    x.append(random.choice(["X", "Y"]))
print(x)
```

Comment: No problem. Make sure to upvote/accept this answer if this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions are a very powerful tool in python that will make this job easier:

```
import random

n=3

myList = [random.choice(['X', 'Y']) for i in range (n**2)]

print myList
```

The list comprehension is denoted by the square brackets.  Within, you provide a pattern for generating the elements in the list, followed by a range or other iterable to bound the number of elements generated.  In this case, the pattern is a random choice from your example list ['X', 'Y'] and the pattern is invoked n^2 times.